# Make javascript injection compatible for api 16

Tags: android, android-webview

I am building an android app that have to be compatible from api 14 and newer. I have 1 method inside an javascript interface.

From api 17 you have to add an annotation to the method, the `@JavascriptInterface`, but the annotation is not supported backwards api, since the app is target for api 14 I got an error. But If I dont add the annotation, the javascript is not trigged in mobile with Android 4.2.

Is it possible to make kind of ifdef if the deviceOs is newer than 4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your build target to be API Level 17. Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to be however old of Android you want to support. Then your code will compile *and* will have the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation. Lint will point out to you places in your code where you use classes, methods, etc. that are newer than your `android:minSdkVersion`, so you can make sure that you are doing so correctly.

Or, set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to 16 or lower, in which case `@JavascriptInterface` is not required. See http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I have now setted the targettSdkVersion to 14, and without `@JavascriptInterface`, but then the javascript method is not trigged. So I will try your first alternative. Thx.